# How to create a variable in a subroutine in DOSBox?

Tags: batch-file, dos, subroutine, dosbox

I'm creating a batch multilanguage installer in DOSBox.

I would like to create a variable in a subroutine which changes the displayed language based on the choice of the user. This is an example of the menu:

```
:installer
@echo off
echo SELECT LANGUAGE
echo [1] French
echo [2] Swedish
choice /c12
if errorlevel 2 goto instswedish
if errorlevel 1 goto instfrench

:instfrench
SET RETURN=okfrench
goto message
:okfrench
copy d:\french.com c:\
exit

:instswedish
SET RETURN=okswedish
goto message
:okswedish
copy d:\swedish.com c:\
exit

:message
echo I will install the software in %LANGUAGE%
choice /c:yn
if errorlevel 2 goto installer
goto %RETURN%
```

Probably I need to set the variable in the `:installer` section, so that `%LANGUAGE%` will display the selected language, but I'm not sure if that's right and I don't know how to do it. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is quite simple because of just two lines must be added to batch file code.

```
:installer
@echo off
echo SELECT LANGUAGE
echo [1] French
echo [2] Swedish
choice /c12
if errorlevel 2 goto instswedish
if errorlevel 1 goto instfrench

:instfrench
SET LANGUAGE=French
SET RETURN=okfrench
goto message
:okfrench
copy d:\french.com c:\
exit

:instswedish
SET LANGUAGE=Swedish
SET RETURN=okswedish
goto message
:okswedish
copy d:\swedish.com c:\
exit

:message
echo I will install the software in %LANGUAGE%
choice /c:yn
if errorlevel 2 goto installer
goto %RETURN%
```

The two inserted lines are:

1. `SET LANGUAGE=French` below the line `:instfrench`
2. `SET LANGUAGE=Swedish` below the line `:instswedish`

That's it.

But the code can be optimized further as shown below:

```
@echo off
:installer
echo Select language:
echo    [1] French
echo    [2] Swedish
choice /c:12
if errorlevel 1 set LANGUAGE=French
if errorlevel 2 set LANGUAGE=Swedish

echo I will install the software in %LANGUAGE%
choice /c:yn
if errorlevel 2 goto installer

copy d:\%LANGUAGE%.com c:\
exit
```

The order of evaluation of `errorlevel` on first choice is important here. The lowest number must be evaluated first and the highest number must be last because of `if errorlevel number` means **IF errorlevel GREATER or EQUAL number**. The environment variable `LANGUAGE` is defined twice on pressing <kbd>2</kbd> for language `Swedish`, first with `French` and next redefined with `Swedish`. But `LANGUAGE` is defined just by first **IF** condition with `French` on pressing <kbd>1</kbd>.

The selected language is used for next user prompt and if the user presses key <kbd>y</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd> also for copying the file.

Comment: You can probably omit the `RETURN` variable by using `goto ok%language%` (I have no DOS/DOSBOX any more, so I can't verify)